# how to get most frequently repeated column A per column B

Tags: sql

I want to get top 2 item mostly ordered by each customer. I can get following data from sales table

```
 ---------------------------
 |OrderAccount| Item        |
 |ABC        |  Shoes #1    |
 |ABC        |  Shoes #2    |
 |ABC        |  Shoes #2    |
 |ABC        |  Shoes #1    |
 |ABC        |  Shoes #4    |
 |RDD        |  Shoes #1    |
 |RDD        |  Shoes #2    |
 |RDD        |  Shoes #1    |
 |RDD        |  Shoes #6    |
 |RDD        |  Shoes #1    |
 ----------------------------
```

how can I get the data though?
this doesn't work:

```
SELECT so.Item,
   so.OrderAccount
  FROM (
       SELECT so.Item,
        so.OrderAccount,
        row_number() OVER(Partition BY so.Item ORDER BY so.OrderAccount desc) as repeated
       FROM SalesOrders so
     WHERE so.Item IS NOT NULL
       ) AS so
  WHERE so.repeated <= 2
  ORDER BY so.OrderAccount
```

Comment: What's the current result, and the wanted result?

Comment: Which DBMS? MS SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work.It will return more than 2 rows if accounts have equal number of orders placed.

```
SELECT b.OrderAccount, b.Item
FROM(
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY a.OrderAccount ORDER BY a.count_item DESC) AS RowRank
    FROM(
        SELECT so.OrderAccount, so.Item, count(item) count_item
        FROM SalesOrders so
        GROUP BY so.OrderAccount, so.Item
    ) a
) b
WHERE b.RowRank <= 2
```

Comment: "It will return more than 2 rows if accounts have equal number of orders placed." - that's a beneficial side effect!

Comment: Just making it clear since the op requested top 2 rows

Answer (score 0):

dude, you just made a mistake about the partition and order by. you want to get top 2 item from each costumer. so you need to partition by costumer, and you have #num in item so you need to order by item.

via:

```
SELECT so.Item,
so.OrderAccount
FROM (
   SELECT so.Item,
    so.OrderAccount,
    row_number() OVER(Partition BY so.OrderAccount ORDER BY so.Item desc) as repeated
   FROM SalesOrders so
 WHERE so.Item IS NOT NULL
   ) AS so
WHERE so.repeated <= 2
ORDER BY so.OrderAccount
```

Comment: Where in this query are the orders counted to determine which items are most frequently ordered per customer?

Comment: Does this work? I agree with underscore_d, the occurrences aren't being counted.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to get a working solution, but it uses really bad practices and will have terrible performance on real-life-databases (OrderAccount renamed to customer and Item renamed to item):

```
-- get the top-product per customer
SELECT customer, item, MAX(cnt) 
FROM (
  -- get all customer-item-pairs with the associated count
  SELECT customer, item, COUNT(item) AS cnt FROM tbl GROUP BY customer,item
) GROUP BY customer

UNION -- combine that with the second-top-product per customer

-- get the top-product per customer, but stripped of the first part of the result (so the second-top-product)
SELECT customer, item, MAX(cnt) 
FROM (
  -- get all customer-item-pairs with the associated count
  SELECT customer, item, COUNT(item) AS cnt FROM tbl GROUP BY customer,item
  EXCEPT --except for the customer-item-pairs which are already top-products
    --this is the same as get the top-product per customer
    SELECT customer, item, MAX(cnt) 
    FROM (
      SELECT customer, item, COUNT(item) AS cnt FROM tbl GROUP BY customer,item
    ) GROUP BY customer
) GROUP BY customer
```

Comment: sorry, but if you have to openly admit your answer is "really bad" and "terrible", it's probably not worth posting