# getting the chance of repetition of frequently occurring values pair

Tags: sql

I want to get top 2 item mostly ordered by each customer. I can get following data from sales table

```
 -----------------------------------------
 |OrderAccount| Item        |  OrderDate  |
 |ABC         | Shoes #1    |  10.01.2016 |
 |ABC         | Shoes #2    |  10.01.2016 |
 |ABC         | Shoes #2    |  13.02.2016 |
 |ABC         | Shoes #1    |  12.12.2016 |
 |ABC         | Shoes #4    |  09.01.2016 |
 |RDD         | Shoes #1    |  01.21.2016 |
 |RDD         | Shoes #2    |  01.22.2016 |
 |RDD         | Shoes #1    |  03.01.2016 |
 |RDD         | Shoes #6    |  03.11.2016 |
 |RDD         | Shoes #1    |  03.21.2016 |
 -----------------------------------------
```

I use the following query mentioned [in earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38118098/how-to-get-most-frequently-repeated-column-a-per-column-b).

```
SELECT b.OrderAccount, b.Item
FROM(
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY a.OrderAccount ORDER BY a.count_item DESC) AS RowRank
    FROM(
        SELECT so.OrderAccount, so.Item, count(item) count_item
        FROM SalesOrders so
        GROUP BY so.OrderAccount, so.Item
    ) a
) b
WHERE b.RowRank <= 2
```

I would like to get more insight from the data: what the chance is that this item will appear in the next sales order (ie in what percentage of the sales order does this item appear for this client)
can I get this information from a query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it:

```
SELECT a.OrderAccount, a.Item, a.Occurrence, b.SalesOrdersPerAccount, 
         CAST(CAST(a.Occurrence AS decimal)/CAST(b.SalesOrdersPerAccount AS decimal)*100 AS  decimal(16,2)) AS Percentage 
FROM
(
   SELECT so.OrderAccount, so.Item, COUNT(*) AS Occurrence FROM SalesOrders so
   WHERE so.Item IS NOT NULL 
   GROUP BY so.OrderAccount, so.Item
) a

LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
   SELECT so.OrderAccount, COUNT(*) AS SalesOrdersPerAccount FROM SalesOrders so
   WHERE so.Item IS NOT NULL
   GROUP so.OrderAccount
) b ON a.OrderAccount = b.OrderAccount

WHERE b.SalesOrdersPerAccount IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY a.OrderAccount, Percentage DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Each row appears to be a separate order, according to the data in your question.  So, I think you can do:

```
SELECT so.OrderAccount, so.Item,
       (count_item * 1.0 / num_orders) as proportion_of_orders
FROM (SELECT so.OrderAccount, so.Item, count(item) as count_item,
             SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY so.OrderAccount) as num_orders,
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY so.OrderAccount ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as rnk
      FROM SalesOrders so
      GROUP BY so.OrderAccount, so.Item
     ) so
WHERE rnk <= 2;
```

Comment: but it is also possible for a sale order to have more than 1 line. what should we do then?

Comment: @Afflatus . . . You should ask another question with appropriate data and desired results.